# CI Not create session

Tags: codeigniter

```
$veri = array("uye_kadi" => $this->input->post('kadi'), 'oturum' => TRUE);
$this->session->set_userdata($veri);
```

Comment: what error it is giving you?

Comment: this code seem alright, only check have you loaded session class or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that you have included session library

either from autoload config file:

```
    $autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

or from controller:

```
    $this->load->library('session');
```

and then
replace your code with :

```
 $veri = array("uye_kadi" => $this->input->post('kadi'), 'oturum' => TRUE);
 $this->session->set_userdata('sess_var_name',$veri);

 echo $this->session->userdata('sess_var_name');
```

Array with can be used as:

```
 $ar = array('user_id'=>900,
        'username'=>'John Doe');

 $this->session->set_userdata('user_details',$ar);

 $this->session->userdata('user_details','user_id'); //Return 900;
```

hope it will help!

Comment: seems there is a typo in your statement in set_userdata and sending array does work

Comment: yup we know now i can delete it :))

Comment: dude @sandip he is passing array to set_userdata that work in CI, do you understand what is the actual  problem?