# codeigniter pass array in session and retrieve

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, session

i want to pass array in codeigniter session and want to retrieve it in another function following is my code where i pass array to session

```
$deliveryData = array(
                    'User_ID' => $this->input->post('User_ID'),
                    'Order_dArea' => $this->input->post('Order_dArea'),
                    'Order_dAddress' => $this->input->post('Order_dAddress'),
                    'Order_PMethod' => $this->input->post('payment_mode'),
                    'Order_dMdate' => $Order_modifieddate
                    );

            $this->session->set_userdata('deliverdata', $deliveryData);
```

i retrieve session in this way

```
$getDeliveryData = $this->session->all_userdata('deliverdata');
```

and i got this output

```
array(12) { ["session_id"]=> string(32) "d369b835203b7da7f9c27e93e6444bd2" ["ip_address"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" ["user_agent"]=> string(65) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0" ["last_activity"]=> int(1372851183) ["user_data"]=> string(0) "" ["cartreturn"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["is_loggedin"]=> int(1) ["login"]=> string(5) "aqeel" ["password"]=> string(10) "ictbeam321" ["cart_contents"]=> array(4) { ["d3d9446802a44259755d38e6d163e820"]=> array(6) { ["rowid"]=> string(32) "d3d9446802a44259755d38e6d163e820" ["id"]=> string(2) "10" ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["price"]=> string(4) "1200" ["name"]=> string(11) "soup item 1" ["subtotal"]=> int(1200) } ["c51ce410c124a10e0db5e4b97fc2af39"]=> array(6) { ["rowid"]=> string(32) "c51ce410c124a10e0db5e4b97fc2af39" ["id"]=> string(2) "13" ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["price"]=> string(4) "1400" ["name"]=> string(11) "soup item 2" ["subtotal"]=> int(1400) } ["total_items"]=> int(2) ["cart_total"]=> int(2600) } ["deliveryfee"]=> int(182) }
```

now i want to get original array values so that i can use it

Comment: See my answer how to pass & access the array data from session in CI here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522177/ci-not-create-session/14522238#14522238

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $deliveryData = array(
                'User_ID' => $this->input->post('User_ID'),
                'Order_dArea' => $this->input->post('Order_dArea'),
                'Order_dAddress' => $this->input->post('Order_dAddress'),
                'Order_PMethod' => $this->input->post('payment_mode'),
                'Order_dMdate' => $Order_modifieddate
                );
    $this->session->set_userdata('deliverdata', $deliveryData);         #to set the session with the above array

    ### for retrieving the session values ###
    $deliveryData   = $this->session->userdata('deliverdata');          #will return the whole array

    ### for retrieving any single element from the session ###
    $userid         = $this->session->userdata['deliverdata']['User_ID'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all session data whereas you only want part of it.  Rather than doing

```
$getDeliveryData = $this->session->all_userdata('deliverdata');
```

I think you just have to do

```
$getDeliveryData = $this->session->userdata('deliverdata');
```

Comment: i want to store array data whereas $this->session->userdata('deliverdata') store only one record can you please guide me in more detail you can get my scenario from my Q

Comment: You can store more than one value if you pass an array which you are doing.  See what the result of $getDeliveryData = $this->session->userdata('deliverdata'); is

Answer (score -1):

```
//first page
$menu_records=array();
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $menu_records);

//second page
var_dump($this->session->userdata['logged_in']);
```